# Clarification of GL.DrawElements parameters

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I am having a hard time to match up the OpenGL specification ([version 3.1](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec31.20090528.pdf), page 27) with common example usage all over the internet.

The OpenGL spec version 3.1 states for DrawElements:

> The command
>
> ```
> void DrawElements(enum mode, sizei count, enum type, void *indices);
> ```
>
> constructs a sequence of geometric primitives by successively transferring the
> count elements whose indices are stored in the currently bound element array
> buffer (see section 2.9.5) at the offset defined by indices to the GL. The i-th element transferred by DrawElements will be taken from element indices[i] of
> each enabled array.

I tend to interpret this as follows:

The indices parameter holds at least *count* values of type *type*. Its elements serve as offsets into the actual element buffer. Since for every usage of DrawElements an element buffer must be currently bound, we actually have 2 obligatory sets of indices here: one in the element buffer and another in the indices array.

This would seem somehow wasting for most situations. Unless one has to draw a model which is defined with an element array buffer but needs to sort its elements back to front due to transparency or so. But how would we achieve to render with the plain element array buffer (no sorting) than ?

Now, strange enough, most examples and tutorials in the internet ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510520/drawelements-use),[here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2005.html) half page down 'Indexed drawing'.) give a single integer as indices parameter, mostly it is 0. Sometimes (void*)0. It is always only a single integer offset - clearly no array for the *indices* parameter!

I have used the last variant (giving a single pointerized integer for *indices*) successfully with some NVIDIA graphics. But I get crashes on Intel on board chips. And I am wondering, who is wrong: me, the spec or thousands of examples. What are the correct parameter and usage of DrawElements? If the single integer is allowed, how does this go along with the spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're tripping over the legacy *glDrawElements* has ever since OpenGL-1.1. Back then there were no VBOs, but just client side arrays, and the program would actually give a pointer (=array in C terms) of indices into the buffer/array set with the *gl…Pointer* functions.

Now with index buffers, the parameter is actually just an offset into the server side buffer. You might be very interested in this SO Question: [What is the result of NULL + int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283714/what-is-the-result-of-null-int)

Also I gave an exhaustive answer there, I strongly recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/8284829/524368

What I wrote about function signatures and typecasts also applies to *glDraw…* calls.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Could you give a link to some official reference that the behavior has changed (and wich would mark the GL spec as false) ?

Comment: @user492238: the Spec is not wrong. Maybe a bit misleading if you read it with some wrong expectations in mind. It clearly states that "indices are stored in the currently bound element array buffer (see section 2.9.5) at the offset defined by indices", and then goes on to mention indices[i], which is simply indices+i in the C-like syntax used by the spec, and that would be byte offset index+sizeof(type)*i in the buffer.

Comment: I would have saved a few hours and been much happier if the spec called out the strange behaviour in a sidenote or something.    Also, if `indices` was a pointer, `indices + i` looks awfully like `indices[i]`